# how to rotate textView in LinearLayout?

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I want to rotate the textView that inside the linearlayout in my project.
But only some part of textView is drown when it rotated.

here is my xml.

```
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Test"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Test"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:rotation="90"
        android:text="TextView" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use `Matrix` for it.

Comment: it seems to be a bug or not full thoughtful made implementation for Android API11 and above. There are many questions like Yours and nobody really get it worked. The most turning to do it programmatically.

Comment: I don't have idea how to implement something like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Programmatically set `TextView` dimensions

We should find the width of the displayed text contained within the `View`, taking consideration the `Font`, and set the `heigh` of the `View` to this.

```
protected void myMethod() {
    //...

    //Get component components paint and text
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String text = (String) textView.getText();
    Paint paint = textView.getPaint();

    //Calculate width of the string given the paint
    int width = (int) paint.measureText(text);

    //Set the minimum width of the component to the width of text contained
    textView.setMinimumHeight(width);

    //...
}
```

[image: Example]